Which group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q^*} /\mathbb{Q^*}^2$?
Let $(\mathbb{Q}^* ,×) $ be the multiplicative group of non-zero rationals and $(\mathbb{Q^*}^2,×)$ be the subgroup formed by squares of rationals.
Which group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q^*} /\mathbb{Q^*}^2$  ?
The quotient group $\mathbb{Q^*} /\mathbb{Q^*}^2$ is such that each element is of order $2$ since $(r\mathbb{Q^*}^2)^2=  \mathbb{Q^*}^2$
Now I guess $\mathbb{Q^*} /\mathbb{Q^*}^2$ is isomorphic to (atmost) a countably infinite abelian group of exponent two something like the power set with symmetric difference as operation or direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but not sure how to eastablish an isomorphism.
Hints Please.

First, notice that in this quotient group, $\frac{1}{p} = p$. Next, construct an isomorphism between your group and $(\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z)^{\mathcal{P}}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers (plus one extra element, for sign purposes). The tricky part is to show that the map you want to use is well defined.

@FrançoisGatine I think the quotient group is isomorphic with a direct sum, rather than a direct product.

@ShuningZhang I am not even getting how to conclude if it's a finite index subgroup or not .

@FrançoisGatine The codomain group is the group of all maps from the set of primes to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  What could be the possible map here ?

@user-492177 You misunderstood. The codomain is $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathcal P} (\mathbb Z / 2\mathbb Z)$.

Yes that is a direct sum instead of product, my apologies.

Any element $a/b \in \mathbf{Q^*}$ can be uniquely expressed as $d^2.a_1/b_1$ where $d$ is a non-zero rational number and $a_1, b_1$ are non-zero square-free relatively prime integers.  But $d^2. a_1/b_1 = d^2/b_1^2 .a_1b_1$. Now map any such element uniquely to the element in the codomain $Z/2 \oplus_{i \in \cal{P}} Z/2$ where
$\pm 1$ occurs in the first component, and to the element in the infinite direct sum given by (1, 1,...p,....) where a prime $p$ occurs for every distinct prime dividing either $a_1$ or $b_1$. This gives a well-defined homomorphism with kernel $\mathbf{Q^*}^2$ and thus an isomorphism between $\mathbf{Q^*}/\mathbf{Q^*}^2$ with the infinite direct sum of $Z/2$ (with itself) indexed not just over all primes but also one extra index for $\pm 1$.
Edit: To make the homomorphism precise in terms of $Z/2$, send each such element $a/b$ to the element in the infinite direct sum which is either $\pm 1$ in the first component (depending on whether $a/b$ is positive or negative), and to the infinite tuple (1, 1, ...-1, ..., -1,...) where $-1$ occurs at each index for which the indexed prime $p$ divides either $a_1$ or $b_1$. For indexed primes $p$ that divide neither $a_1$ nor $b_1$, the entries in the infinite tuple would be $+1$. It is easy to verify that this is a homomorphism. (Above, I have used the symbol $p$ only for descriptive purposes; it should be $-1$ for precision.)  I hope it is more clear now.

You need an infinite direct sum, not a direct product.

That is why I mentioned that it is not surjective.  But perhaps infinite direct sum is more accurate.  Thank you for correcting me -- I will edit my post.

The point is if you use the direct sum, you get a surjective map.

@AnuradhaNarasimhan I don't understand "to the element in the infinite direct sum given by $(1 ,1, ..p,..)$ " .Do you mean $1$ occur only at those indices where the corresponding prime divides either $a_1$ or $b_1$ ?

The other way round -- 1 occurs at every index for which the indexed prime does not divide $a_1$ or $b_1$.  The non-trivial entries are at each distinct prime dividing either $a_1$ or $b_1$.

The non-trivial entries can be denoted by $-1$ instead of $p$ (but it does not really matter; for each indexed prime $p$, define $p^2 =1$ in $Z/2$).  It is just for the sake of making the homomorphism clear that I have denoted the entry by $p$ rather than $-1$.

@AnuradhaNarasimhan  I have some confusion  why should there be a $p$ in a component of ordered tuples formed by direct sum of copies of $Z_2$ . Please if you can clarify and write the specific homomorphism in a bit detail , I would be glad to accept your answer.

I have added an edit to my post -- I hope it is more clear now.

More generally, when $R$ is a factorial ring with set of prime elements $P$ (up to associates), then we have an isomorphism of abelian groups
$$R^{\times} \oplus \bigoplus_{p \in P} \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow Q(R)^{\times}, \quad (u,(z_p)_{p \in P}) \mapsto u \cdot \prod_{p \in P} p^{z_p}.$$
Bijectivity is just the definition of a factorial ring, and the homomorphic property is easily verified. Any isomorphism of additively written abelian groups $A \cong B$ induces an isomorphism $A/2A \cong B/2B$ of the associated abelian groups "modulo 2" (these are actually vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_2$). For a multiplicatively written group $A$ we will write $A/A^2$ for that. And of course, $(A \oplus B)/2(A \oplus B) \cong A/2A \oplus B/2B$. Hence,
$$Q(R)^{\times} / (Q(R)^{\times})^2 \cong R^{\times} / (R^{\times})^2 \oplus \bigoplus_{p \in P} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$
For $R = \mathbb{Z}$ we have $R^{\times} = \{+1,-1\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, every unit squares to $1$, and thus
$$\mathbb{Q}^{\times} / (\mathbb{Q}^{\times})^2 \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \bigoplus_{p \text{ prime}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus \omega}.$$

Beautiful answer. I'm sure you know this, but for the OP, the first isomorphism you write down is a special case of the exact sequence $0 \to R^{\times} \to Q(R)^{\times} \to Div(R) \to Cl(R) \to 0$ for Krull domains, if I'm not mistaken. If $R$ is factorial, then every height one prime ideal is principal, so $Div(R)$ is just the free abelian group on prime elements of $R$ up to associates. Moreover, $Cl(R) = 0$, so the sequence $0 \to R^{\times} \to Q(R)^{\times} \to Div(R) \to 0$ is exact, and is split by the map $Div(R) \to Q(R)^{\times}$ that you write down in your first sentence.

The other answers have addressed this nicely, but I can't help but elaborating on my comment on Martin's beautiful answer. This will be less elementary than the other answers, but it shows how this group can be computed using one of my favorite exact sequences.
First, a definition: a domain $R$ with field of fractions $K$ is said to be a Krull domain if it satisfies the following three conditions:

Letting $H_{1}(R)$ denote the set of all height-one prime ideals of $R$, the localization $R_{P}$ is a discrete valuation ring for every $P \in H_{1}(R)$.
$R = \cap_{P \in H_{1}(R)} R_{P}$ as subrings of $K$, where $R_{P}$ is embedded via the canonical localization map.
For any nonzero $x \in R$, $x$ is contained in finitely many $P \in H_{1}(R)$.

For example, every integrally closed Noetherian domain is a Krull domain. Our example of interest is the case when $R$ is a UFD, as I claim that every UFD which is not a field is a Krull domain. Indeed, it is a straightforward exercise that every height one prime ideal of a UFD is principal, generated by a nonzero prime element. (Take a nonzero element of such an ideal, factor it into primes, and see what gives.) Then our conditions can be verified as follows:

Since every height one ideal $P$ is principal and generated by a nonzero prime $p$, the localization $R_{P}$ is a UFD with one prime element, namely $p/1$. By unique factorization, $R_{P}$ is then a local PID, hence a DVR. (If you like, you can directly construct the valuation, which is just the usual $p$-adic valuation.)

This is a standard exercise, which can be proven using the so-called ideal of denominators.

This is merely the statement that any nonzero element has only finitely many divisors.


For any Krull domain $R$, we can construct the following beautiful exact sequence. Let $\operatorname{Div}(R)$ be the free abelian group on $H_{1}(R)$. Consider the morphism $\partial \colon K^{\times} \to \operatorname{Div}(R)$ defined by
$$x \mapsto \sum_{P \in H_{1}(R)} v_{P}(x)[P],$$
where $v_{P}$ is the $P$-adic valuation on $K^{\times}$ associated to the DVR $R_{P}$.
We have one more definition before I can get to the point. In general, the map $\partial$ is not surjective, so let $\operatorname{Cl}(R)$ denote the cokernel of $\partial$. I claim that there is an exact sequence of abelian groups
$$0 \to R^{\times} \to K^{\times} \to \operatorname{Div}(R) \to \operatorname{Cl}(R) \to 0,$$
where the map $K^{\times} \to \operatorname{Div}(R)$ is given by $\partial$. Indeed, the only place where exactness isn't immediate is at $K^{\times}$. No prime ideal of $R$ contains any element of $R^{\times}$, so one containment is obvious. The other containment can be deduced by noting that if $x \in K^{\times}$ has $v_{P}(x) = 0$ for $P \in H_{1}(R)$, then $x \in R_{P}$ by the definition of the discrete valuation $v_{P}$. Therefore, if $v_{P}(x) = 0$ for all $P \in H_{1}(R)$, then $x \in R$ by condition 2. On the other hand, the same is true for $1/x$ since $\partial$ is a homomorphism, so $1/x \in R$, whence $x \in R^{\times}$.
This brings us to your question. When $R$ is a UFD, the map $\partial$ is manifestly surjective, since if $P \in H_{1}(R)$ is generated by $p$, then $p^{n}$ maps to $n[P]$. Therefore, $\operatorname{Cl}(R) = 0$, and the sequence
$$0 \to R^{\times} \to K^{\times} \to \operatorname{Div}(R) \to 0$$
is exact. Since $\operatorname{Div}(R)$ is free, hence projective, this sequence is split, and we deduce $K^{\times} \cong R^{\times} \oplus \operatorname{Div}(R)$. The other answers tell you how to take it from here.
If you want to describe the splitting $\operatorname{Div}(R) \to K^{\times}$, it's very simple to be explicit: again, if you just take $p$ to be a generator of $P \in H_{1}(R)$, you send $k[P]$ to $p^{k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. And indeed, since principal ideals in a domain are classified by their generators up to associates, $\operatorname{Div}(R)$ is just the free abelian group on the set of primes of $R$ up to associates, and the maps described in my answer recover exactly the maps so nicely explained in Martin's answer.

Incidentally, this is all part of a much larger and beautiful story which belongs to number theory, algebraic geometry, and K-theory. I recommend reading the treatment in Weibel's K-book - if I have time, I'll edit my answer above with a more precise reference and delete this comment.
